# How to have a different transition animation on hover off with two transform properties in CSS Only?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an animation logo translate and rotate by 360deg when hovered, but only translate without rotating when hovering off. Here's what I have so far :

```css
.check {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.check:hover {
  transform: translateX(-100px) rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="check">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML markup and all relevant CSS, preferably in a functional snippet so we can see the issue in action.

Comment: @DBS, here's a simplified snippet,

Comment: It is working just fine in the newest Firefox and Google Chrome. What browser are you using? And on what device?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó, is it translating back to its original place without rotating, for you ? Because, for me, it does both when hovering off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution I found, so far, is to add wrapper and separate responsibilities.

```css
.check {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wraper{
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;

}
.wraper:hover{
  transform: translateX(-100px) ;
}

.check:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
        <div class="wraper">
            <div class="check">Hello</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I've gotta do it CSS only

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it helped you and mark it as solution if it solved your issue. Have a nice day!